# c++11 getline asking two times the input

Tags: c++, c++11, xcode4.3

In xcode 4.3 I have set the project to use c++11: I changed the voice c++ language dialect to c++11, and c++ standard library to "libc++ ( LLVM c++ standard library with c++11 support)".
Then I tried to compile and execute this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char buffer[100];
    cin.getline(buffer,100);
    cout << buffer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it asks two times the input.For example I type "hello" and the stream remains opened, waiting for another string.If I type another string then it prints out "hello".
If I don't use c++11 this problem doesn't occur.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I want to take in input maximum 100 characters without using std::string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in libc++.  My apologies.  It is fixed on Mountain Lion.  You can work around it by using `getline(istream&, string&)` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::string buffer;
    getline(cin, buffer);
    cout << buffer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```